# seet the cron job but why the order mail will auto cc to other customers?

Tags: email, magento, cron

Set the cron job, but the order email will auto cc to other customers and I don't know why. Email configuration and setup are proper, and only "order email " will be auto cc, the shipment,invoice email and account email didn't have this problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's your Magento version ? 1.x ?

Answer (score 0):

You have customer address email in `core_email_queue_recipients` table who is not removed.
The task launch by cron job get email recipients in this table.

You can run this SQL script before your initial cron job run

```
DELETE 
  FROM `core_email_queue_recipients` 
  WHERE `core_email_queue_recipients`.`message_id` NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT `core_email_queue`.`message_id` 
    FROM `core_email_queue`
  )
```